# Python Docx Lib - Opening Word

Tags: python, docx

Novice programmer here. I'm trying to learn how to open/edit/save word document files. I'm on windows 7 64bit and have Microsoft Word 2010. I'm following this guide: https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html

I'm following the first section "Opening a document" and type in the first two lines and nothing opens. So I must be doing something wrong. Can't get word to open at all. Any advice?

Comment: Can you include your code explicitly in the post? Providing the link is good, but links go stale.

Answer (score 2):

what are you trying to do ... thats creating a new document ... not opening it in word

to open a file

```
os.startfile(r"C:\Some\Folder\doc1.docx")
```

what `docx` (python module you referenced) is for is creating new docx files that you can then  open in word after you have created them

consider the following

```
from docx import Document
import os
document = Document() #create a new document
paragraph = document.add_paragraph('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.')
document.save('test.docx') #save it to the filesystem
os.startfile("test.docx") #open it with the default handler for docx (usually word)
```

Comment: Thanks, mate. I guess I wasn't sure if after calling document() that Word is suppose to open and you can see the action happening in real time.

Comment: And for what I'm wanting to do... I have reports I have to make at work. We have a template so I'll basically type a bunch of info in and paste pngs generated from excel as graphs and boom, you have a report. But I want this automated for it takes waaaaaaaaaay too much time to repeat "copy/paste" over and over for a bunch of data. after looking around, seems that python-docx will be a good choice